# magento 2 add static block on category page left sidebar only

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, category, layout, xml

I have override Module-Catalog into my theme's folder.

I want to add custom blocks in category sidebar. so in **catalog_category_View.xml** file i have added following code which works if i put it in **default.xml** file but it doesn't work for **catalog_category_view.xml** file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="top_left_sidebar">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">top_left_sidebar</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

I want to show that block for category page left column only.   How can i do that?

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to edit your xml files. Just add a cms block to your design layout.

In your Magento Backend go to the category>design
insert into the xml layout update area

```
<referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="Your_CMS_Block">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">Your_CMS_Block</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
 </referenceContainer>
```

I always use the same name for both the cms block name and the identifier when I create the block.

The only reason I'd edit the XML for this is if you are building this shop for a client and you don't want them to be able to go in and change what you did.

Answer (score 1):

First ensure that  layout file name **catalog_category_view.xml** `v` should be **lowercase**  instead of **Uppercase**.

If it is not worked then  changes the **`referenceContainer`**  name  to `sidebar.main` from `sidebar.additional`.

### **Or can do by Widget**

Goto admin >Content>Widget . Create a new widget

On this widget select

*Type: CMS STATIC BLOCK*

*Layout Updates:*

- Display On:Anchor Categories and All Categories
- Display On:Non-Anchor Categories and All Categories

[image]

*and on Widget Options tab select your cms static.*

This is best solution

Comment: Thanks amit for your answer.  catalog_category_view.xml   name in lower case. Yes i know can be added from admin but in my module if i want to add it through <referenceContainer >  then it doesn't work.  I did try  sidebar.main and sidebar.additional but not working.  Did check vendor file and if i add  that code in that file it works.  As we should not edit vendor file we have rewritten this file in my custom theme folder and adding <referenceContainer name="sidebar.addition">  but not working.    What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Instead on `catalog_category_view.xml` use `catalog_category_view_type_layered.xml` to add the container you want to use for the widget